# Why doesn't SVN hook (post commit) execute?

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I am trying to execute post-commit hook and no matter what I do I always get:

```
Command: Commit  
Modified: C:\****\somefile.txt
Sending content: C:\****\somefile.txt
Completed: At revision: XX  
Error: post-commit hook failed (exit code 255) with no output.
```

Currently my post-commit script looks like this:

```
echo TEST >> /srv/subversion/smth/hooks/test.log
```

I also tried with empty file, with svn update on specific directory and all variations work fine if I run theme as `su www-data ./post-commit` from shell.

Repo is accessed over http (apache) so www-data is user which is executing this. My server is on Ubuntu 11.10 and SVN server version is 1.6.12...

Here are privileges for post-commit file:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 51 2014-06-05 11:52 post-commit
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `www-data` account has enough privileges to write to `/srv/subversion/smth/hooks/test.log`. For example, run the command and check the result:

`sudo -u www-data echo TEST >> /srv/subversion/smth/hooks/test.log`

Comment: If i run this command as root it works... If I run as other user it doesn't. In post-commit I also tried just this: 'echo TEST' and I still get the same error (no logs are written)